# Metamask now longer interacts with PetShop Dapp

Tags: ethereum

Since November the 4th - In order for MetaMask to interact with your webpage dapps, you need to implement the windows.ethereum.enable as part of your scripts

I have run through the pet shop tutorial - https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop - everything works as expected

but metamask is no longer working - can anyone assist as to how i would implement the code change above into the existing script for the pet shop tutorial

PS: I downloaded the pet shop dapp a while ago and was looking into getting it to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to download the latest version of the pet shop app, but more information can be found on the ethereum stack exchange

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61794/metamask-now-longer-interacts-with-petshop-dapp/61803#61803

Answer (score 0):

I tried it yesterday actually and it worked for me. Just go to the page, they upgraded the code. https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop